# Problem with cloudwatch_exporter metrics in prometheus and grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, exporter

My problem is that having the same configuration on 30 servers, the metric does not work on some of them. Out of 30 servers, 10 work, and for some reason, 20 don't. But at the same time, other metrics can work correctly on all servers.
To collect metrics, I use [cloudwatch_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter) in docker. The config looks like this

```
---
region: eu-west-1

# Request data that spans this range:
range_seconds: 60
# Request data that is already this old:
delay_seconds: 60
# How often do we query AWS?
#period_seconds: 60


##cpucredit
metrics:

  - aws_namespace: AWS/EC2
    aws_metric_name: CPUCreditBalance
    period_seconds: 3600
    aws_dimensions: [InstanceId]
    aws_statistics: [Average]
    aws_tag_select:
      tag_selections:
        Name: ["NAME prod env"]
      resource_type_selection: "ec2:instance"
      resource_id_dimension: InstanceId

  - aws_namespace: AWS/RDS
    aws_metric_name: BufferCacheHitRatio
    period_seconds: 360
    aws_dimensions: [DBInstanceIdentifier]
    aws_statistics: [Average]
    aws_dimension_select_regex:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: [databasename]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/RDS
    aws_metric_name: FreeableMemory
    period_seconds: 60
    aws_dimensions: [DBInstanceIdentifier]
    aws_statistics: [Average]
    aws_dimension_select_regex:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: [databasename]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/RDS
    aws_metric_name: CPUUtilization
    period_seconds: 60
    aws_dimensions: [DBInstanceIdentifier]
    aws_statistics: [Average]
    aws_dimension_select_regex:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: [databasename]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/RDS
    aws_metric_name: DatabaseConnections
    period_seconds: 3600
    aws_dimensions: [DBInstanceIdentifier]
    aws_statistics: [Average]
    aws_dimension_select_regex:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: [databasename]

  - aws_namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
    aws_metric_name: RequestCount
    period_seconds: 86400
    delay_seconds: 60
    range_seconds: 86400
    aws_dimensions: [LoadBalancer, TargetGroup]
    aws_dimension_select_regex:
      TargetGroup: ["(.*)group1(.*)"]
    aws_statistics: [Sum]
```

This config, corrected for the name of the tags, are the same on all servers. After that I restart docker compose on server, And I check that the enpoint is available in prometheus and that metrics are collected.

```
##This is my endpoint in prometheus config
  - job_name: 'cloudwatch_insnace'
    scrape_interval: 300s
    static_configs:
         - targets: ['instancedns.com:9106']
```

After that, I go to grafana and see that this server is not in the list of instances.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvTGs.png)

There are only 8 out of 30. Prometheus has a connection to these endpoints (all 30). And there are metrics that are displayed from each server. But for some reason there is no such metric.

I also tried to find this metric in the list of metrics. But I didn't find it. But the situation is the same on instances that display the balance correctly. Maybe I don't understand how it should work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvwu.png)

There is nothing in the logs of the exporter, prometheus and grafana that would indicate a problem

Please tell me what could be the problem

I tried changing the metrics collection time in the exporter config. Changed the config in every possible way.

I expect that this metric, as well as others, will be displayed in grafana and correctly taken from prometheus

Comment: And do you see metrics of all services at Prometheus graph page and all monitored instances at targets?

Comment: @markalex Yes, all targets in prometheus work (there is a connection)